# Producing Video Lectures similar to Coursera/EDX

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording, audio-recording, audio-quality

I would like to record video lectures using a light board scenario which is a transparent board on which one can draw as if one is drawing on the screen/camera itself. For those of you interested, here's how you can create such a set up:

I have a similar set up of the light board itself but I have the following two issues that I would like to have some feedback on:

1. For the initial tests we used a Sony-DCR-SX65E camera. The quality of the video was tremendously bad but the more evident problem was the fact that we didn't have a proper lighting so it was very hard to distinguish the writings on the board. Obviously a better camera is needed but would the camera itself be sufficient if it has good enough configuration options or we have to consider additional lights as well? I'm curious if we can fit around 1000-1500$ budget to have a professional looking video?
2. A bit off topic, but the bluetooth headset microphone that we used also produced horrible audio quality. Any idea of easy to use portable microphone that we can use? Audio quality is of most importance but it would be a nice bonus to be able to easily use the microphone i.e. plug it in directly via USB instead of needing additional audio interface to use it?

Comment: I don't feel like I have enough information to give you to post a full answer but check this question out as some of the things you ask for are discussed there as well: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/what-equipment-do-i-need-to-be-able-to-produce-hd-quality-videos?rq=1

Comment: What I can say: The max. resolution of the camera you have is quite low. You'll want one that records in at least 1280x720. Something like or similar to the Sony Handycam HDR-PJ810E probably. Besides recording in 720p/i you'll need to be able to plug in a mic to it.

Comment: Lastly: yes, you'll most likely want to invest in some proper lighting equipment. Check out the question I linked for more info.